# Trying to create symlink - keep getting error: "File exists"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, symlink, rack-pow

I am trying to use [Pow](http://pow.cx/) and create a symlink so that I can ultimately run my rails application locally at the following URL:

http://market_place_api.dev/

I am going through the [API's on Rails tutorial](http://apionrails.icalialabs.com/book), and when I follow the [author's instructions](http://apionrails.icalialabs.com/book/chapter_one#sec-pow_prax) on setting up Pow and a symlink, here is what is happening:

1. cd into a folder called "code", and created a new rails app: `$ rails new market_place_api -T`
2. Installed Pow: `$ curl get.pow.cx | sh`
3. Gone to the Pow directory: `$ cd ~/.pow`
4. **And here is where the problem occurs.**  The instructions say to symlink: `$ ln -s /path/to/myapp`
5. In my case, the app is located at this URL:  `/Users/harrylevine/Dropbox/Coding/BLOC/code/market_place_api`
6. So I enter into the command line: `$ ln -s /Users/harrylevine/Dropbox/Coding/BLOC/code/market_place_api` and I keep getting **this error:** `ln: ./market_place_api: File exists`

I have tried many variations of this, including:

- applying this format:  `ln -s target_path link_path`

All to no avail.

How can I properly create this symlink so that I can ultimately run my rails application locally at the following URL:

http://market_place_api.dev/

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means that there is already a file (or a sym-link) called market_place_api in that directory (~/.pow).

Check with `$ ls -l` to see what the file is. If it's the correct sym-link then you are ready to proceed with the tutorial.

Comment: This worked.  Thanks @algomatic !  I checked as you described, and there was a file already in there.  An incorrect one.  I removed it, and recreated the symlink using:  $ ln -s /Users/harrylevine/Dropbox/Coding/BLOC/code/market_place_api